# Making a web form translator that uses a .csv file

Tags: c#, webforms, streamreader

I'm writing a web form that can convert abbreviations into their actual meaning. I'm using a .csv file with two columns separated by a ';' (that can change if needs be). The first column is going to be the user input (so the abbreviation) and the second column will be the output (the meaning). I'm fairly new to C# so I'm struggling a little but I think I'm on the right path with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // let's ignore case when comparing.

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:/dictionary.csv")))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] tokens = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                    _dictionary[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
                }
            }
        }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {


         string output;
                if(_dictionary.TryGetValue(TextBox1, out TextBox2))
                return TextBox2;

                throw new Exception("Input not recognised");
            }    
        }

    }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated. The webform consists of the input (textbox1) the button and the output (textbox2)

EDIT for clarity

This wont run...

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Is this part of a larger application? I'm slightly confused as to why you're using C# to do this rather than something that might be a little more portable such as an HTML file with JavaScript. PS. Looks like you should use `TryGetVale(TextBox1.Text, out output)`.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Ive been asked to do it in C#, its going to be part of a webservice

Comment: [Here's some useful info regarding working with CSV files in C#](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp‎‎)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is good form, but for the simple use you have it should work:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string output;
    if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(TextBox1.Text, out output))
    {
        TextBox2.Text = output;
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox2.Text = "Input not recognised";
    }
}
```